# How to develop libraries for symfony while keeping the library code framework independent

Tags: php, symfony, github, autoload

I'm creating an app in Symfony which is using a library I'm writing at the same time.

While my application is being built with symfony, I want the component library to be completely framework independent as it needs to be reusable by applications not necessarily written in symfony.

Therefore I have a symfony bundle which integrates the library (the component)

The folder structure is a follows

```
src/MyVendor/
|-- Bundle
|   `-- MyComponentBundle
|       |-- Controller
|       |-- DependencyInjection
|       |-- Resources
|       |   |-- config
|       |   `-- views
|       |       `-- Default
|       |-- Tests
|           `-- Controller
|               `-- MyObjectControllerTest.php
|       `-- MyComponentBundle.php
`-- Component
    `-- MyComponent
        |-- doc
        |-- src
            `-- MyObject.php
        |-- test
            `-- MyObjectTest.php
        |-- .gitignore
        |-- composer.json
        |-- LICENSE
        |-- README.md
        `-- phpunit.xml.dist
```

Questions:

1. Is `MyComponent` directory structure correct as per the PSR-x Autoloading standards? For example, how do I use `MyObject` from the library inside the bundle, i.e. in `MyObjectControllerTest.php`
2. Can `MyObject` reside in the namespace of `MyVendor\MyComponent`? If not, how do I have to amend the directory structure so that (1) I can use that namespace, and (2) so that it can be autoloaded inside `MyObjectControllerTest.php`, i.e. `new MyVendor\MyComponent\MyObject();` will work; right now I'm getting `PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyVendor\MyComponent\MyObject' not found in ...`
3. Could you please direct me to an online resource to help me to publish `MyComponent` on github and make it available to symfony (I'm guessing most of that involves just setting up composer.json correctly)

Thank you

Comment: Consider picking a simple Symfony component such as Yaml and following it's structure.

Comment: thanks, I did look at that but the difficulty I'm having is that with existing Symfony components I see the structure only starts with the component's root, but not the structure where that root is placed while being developed. I mean that in I see `symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml` in the `vendors` folder which is the published dir structure, but I don't see how I could add a `doc`, `test` and `src` folder for each component

Comment: composer.json allows you to specify vendors directory structure.  When developing, make you own directory structure.  In your case you will have a MyVendor/Component directory with the Object repository under it.  It is confusing at first,  Wish I could point you to a step by step tutorial but I don't know of any.

Comment: During development, add a line to app/autoload.php with something like: $loader->add('MyVendor',   __DIR__  . '/../../MyVendor');

Comment: thanks, i did try that but still get the class not found exception

Answer (score 5):

1. It's compatible with PSR-x autoloaders. But your namespaces should be properly registered ([PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md), [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)).
2. You should create proper autoload to use your component ([using composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload), for example).
3. Just [create a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) for your component on github, [create](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) your `composer.json` (or copy/past and edit some side one), submit your package [on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) (just insert github project link)

Comment: For private repos, Satis ( https://github.com/composer/satis ) is a drop-in Packagist replacement.

Comment: Thank you that clarifies a lot. I'm still unsure where I need to register the namespace while the component is still in dev (i.e. not submitted to packagelist). Do I do that with code, or composer.json with the `"autoload": { "psr-0: " { "MyVendor: "path/to/src" }}`

Comment: Better do it with composer and also add this lib to your bundle as dependency using composer too.

Comment: i will be grateful if someone  suggest me a great book to learn how to create php and symfony advanced libraries .